# Forward a thread of messages in Mail

Tags: macos, mail.app

In **Mail** on Mac OS X Lion, is there a way to select an entire thread of messages and forward them to someone in a single e-mail?

Ideally I'm looking for a simple command in Mail (press <kbd>⌘</kbd> while selecting, or something like that), but I'm open to a more complex (AppleScript?) solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is start a new mail message to your recipient, then select the messages that you want to forward and drag them over to the new mail. They will be sent as attachments to your desired recipient.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like things have changed in Lion - I'm running 10.6.8 - but with threading enabled in Mail.app it's easy.  Select the thread header (which shows the subjects listed in the viewer window below) and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. The messages and contents, attachments, etc. are compiled into one new email, ready to be forwarded to a new recipient or group.

[image]

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of selecting a thread header? I'm having trouble doing it.